# Playing video using AVPlayer does not get resume when come in foreground ios

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am playing video using AVPlayer. When I go in background player is paused and when it is brought in foreground player is played. But still video is not appearing though it contains URL in its current Item. I am stuck and not getting and solution.Please help me to resolve. Thanks in advance.

Below code is used to play initially:-

```
       let item1 = AVPlayerItem.init(URL: NSURL(string:path))
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item1)

        layer?.player = player;
        player?.play()
```

Below code is used to pause and resume:-

```
   func pausePlayerOnBackgroundAppearance()
    {
        if(player != nil)
        {
        player?.pause()
        }
    }

    func resumePlayerOnForegroundAppearance()
    {
        if(player != nil)
       {
            player?.play()
        }
    }
```

If I am seeking some time to play video at some time where it was paused before then also it is not playing video

```
func pausePlayerOnBackgroundAppearance()
    {
        if(player != nil){
            let currentItem:AVPlayerItem = player!.currentItem
             currentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(currentItem.currentTime())
                player?.pause()
        }
    }
func resumePlayerOnForegroundAppearance()
    {
        if(player != nil){
            player!.seekToTime(CMTimeMake(Int64(currentTime!), 1))
            player?.play()
        }
}
```